# Which one is correct: "dir" or "dich"? Dative or Accusative?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn’t “Ich danke dir” “Ich danke dich?”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5936/why-isnt-ich-danke-dir-ich-danke-dich)

If when I'm talking with a German, and I want to thank him/her which one is correct? *Ich danke dich* is correct or *Ich danke dir*? And why?

Answer (score 5):

> Ich danke Dir

This is always correct, and "Ich danke Dich" is always incorrect. The receiver of something is always in Dativ.

Note that "Dativ" comes from Latin *do, dare, dedi, **datus***, which means primarily *to give*. So *Dativ* is literally the case you use to describe the act of giving to someone.