# Macht Spaß and its usage

Tags: grammar

Why is it dative in the sentence "Das macht mir Spaß" and "Macht es dir Spaß"? What is acting on what in these two sentences?

Answer (score 7):

According to [this online resource](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dative_case):

> [The Dative] Case [is] used to express direction towards an indirect object, the receiver, and is generally indicated in English by to or for with the objective case.

The unspecified subject *es* in your sentence is providing *fun* (accusative) to *me* (dative). As I, sort of, receive *having fun*, I am put in the dative case.

For comparison a (grammatically) similar sentence (subject, predicate, indirect object (dative), direct object (accusative)):

> Er gibt mir einen Apfel.

Answer (score 4):

"Das" and "es" depend on the context: they refer the ongoing activity, whatever you're doing at the time or enjoying (e.g., watching). Compare it to "it (the play) amuses me".

"Viel Spaß beim Fußball[spiel]!" would be "have a lot of fun at the soccer game", no matter if you're playing or just watching.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not used to grammar terms, so I will show some examples.

**Wem** macht es Spaß? Das macht **mir** Spaß. Macht es **Dir** Spaß?

What actually is fun is not mentioned in the sentences. **Es** and **das** refer to something mentioned in the sentence before or something that is actually happening.

**Added** (Trying to make it clearer)

Because the dativ case is nearly lost in the English language, it's a bit difficult to show good examples. Normally I would say "Do you have fun?", translating this to German you will get "Hast Du Spaß?". Trying to translate "Macht es Dir Spaß?" to English, I would say "Does it make fun to you?"

The difference between "Macht es **Dir** Spaß?" and "Macht es **Dich** glücklich?" is that "Spaß" is a thing by itself while "glücklich" is the state of another thing. You **have** fun, but you **are** happy.

Comment: Getting better ;) – Difficult to translate, because in English you doesn't apply an object. "It's fun" and not "It's fun to me". Actually, that's why I don't understand why the question comes up. You don't say "It makes me fun" in English. The answer would be the same as to a similar question about [danken](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5936/1224) anyway.

Comment: @Em1: We do say "I'm having fun", though, which isn't a million miles away

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Ich habe Spaß" is very common in German, too. "Ich habe Spaß daran, etwas zu tun" or "Ich habe Spaß an etwas"